# $f: X \to Y$ is a submersion, $X$ is compact and $Y$ is connected - why $f(X)$ is open?

Tags: differential-topology

$f: X \to Y$ is a submersion,  $X$ is compact and $Y$ is connected - why $f(X)$ is open?

Assume I have proved that for an open set $U \subset X$, $f(U)$ is open.

Thank you.

Comment: $X \subset X$ is open.

Comment: Thank you @fuglede. I'd like to accept is as an answer if you care to put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any topological space $X$, $X \subseteq X$ is open.